# HiddenField.value becomes blank when disabled in IE - How do I prevent this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a datagrid that has rows and I keep track of several ID's that relate to the row with a couple of asp:HiddenField elements.  However there is a case where I'm disabling the entire datagrid and then all of the values of the hidden fields become blank.  This only happens in IE(using ver 8) and not in Chrome or FF.

So what's the best workaround for this? Or even better, how can I prevent the values from blanking out?

Comment: Not only in IE but everywhere. (IMHO) make it readonly instead of disabled. ( or create another alias (hidden field) which will hold this value)

Comment: Disabled inputs do NOT get sent to the server.